# How is the quota of Google Maps Places API calculated?

Tags: python, google-maps, google-api, python-requests

I have a list of names for finding out the detail address and coordinates, just like what a user search for on Google Maps app, instead I try to accomplish the task in batch.

I did it in Python with "Requests" package.

I used Google Maps Places API and "textsearch" mode. After sending 100 requests (each contains a string of names of one place), I found in the API console that the free quota (1,000 request / 24h) was exceeded, while the count of "success" was 100.

Why does Google records 1,000 requests while in fact I sent 100?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is asking about google maps api and their service

Comment: @EdChum I did search on Google and Stackoverflow but find no answers. As shown on the Google Maps API website, the "forum" link is redirected to StackOverflow. If it is inappropriate to discuss Google API here, I am sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/search#TextSearchRequests), text searches are subject to a 10-times multiplier:

> **Text Search Requests**

-- snip --

> The Google Places search services share the same usage limits. **However, the Text Search service is subject to a 10-times multiplier**. That is, each Text Search request that you make will count as 10 requests against your quota. If you've purchased the Google Places API as part of your Google Maps API for Work contract, the multiplier may be different. Please refer to the Google Maps API for Work documentation for details.